# Access to Cloudformation stack output executed by code pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I wish to access to the output of a CFN stack ran by a codepipeline.
For that I understand that I need to add output artifacts to my action.
But the data I get from that when I look in S3 is binnary. How is it supposed to be decoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the data I get from that when I look in S3 is binnary.

This is just a **zip file without an extension**. So you can un-zip it with any archiving program if you want to inspect its content. If you still struggle, manually add zip extension to it.